# SharePoint Online - Create new document from custom templates

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

Is it possible to have a custom template added to a document library in SharePoint Online?
I know there are some default templates but I want custom ones.

Comment: Meaning like a custom Word template or Excel template new items can be created off of?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can add custom document templates to Document Library in SharePoint Online. See this [link](http://blog.blksthl.com/2014/02/04/office-365-guide-series-using-your-document-templates-in-sharepoint-online/) on how to add custom document template.